# How to create unique id from number of elements, like an array in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am using [this recursive menu](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/recursive-menu-umbraco-45), and have done some alterations. What I want on the first level li tags is a id with an unique number. So the id of the first one is id="mid0", second one is id="mid1" and so on. How can this be done?

I'm new to XSLT so forgive me for asking probably a stupid question, but I have tried searching for it and I can't find what I'm looking for.

```
<xsl:if test="count($currentPage/ancestor::root/* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor::root/* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
<li class="twocol">
<a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = current()/@id">
<xsl:attribute name="class">Selected</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
</a>
<xsl:if test="count(current()/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
<xsl:call-template name="submenu">
<xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</li>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

The li with class "twocol" is where I need the id so it ends up like this in the output:

```
<li id="mid0" class="twocol">
<li id="mid1" class="twocol">
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include your input XML (or a simplified version of it) and the desired output structure.

Comment: I tried, but it all turns into just one long line of code. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within XSLT `for-each` blocks, there have a nice little function called `position()` which will provide you the current index of the items matching the `for-each` statement. Combined with a conditional attribute tag (for only level 1 items), adding the following code should get you what you need:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor::root/* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
    <li class="twocol">

        <!-- NEW CODE -->
        <xsl:if test="$level = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">mid<xsl:value-of select="position()-1" /></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- / NEW CODE -->

        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
            <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = current()/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">Selected</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Yeah, couldn't remember if it was zero-indexed. Could just trying doing `position()-1`. I'm not in a position to test code at the moment.